# Size of /tmp folder keeps on increasing

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu, files, tmp, azure

I have a ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine on azure, with a OS disk of size 30 GB.

If I keep the machine running for several days, the size of the /tmp folder increases upto 21 GB, and adding up other folders it reaches its limit i.e., 30 GB and the VM stops functioning.

Yes, after restarting the VM the size of /tmp folder is back to 1 GB and the VM starts functioning. But, I do not want to restart the system everytime the limit is reached.

Could anyone please help me with any other solution for this issue?

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: 14.04 is EOL by the way, and not supported any more here.  As for the system constantly using up /tmp/ that's not a **good thing** and should be investigated, as it sounds like you've got something doing things it shouldn't or not cleaning up after itself.  Alternatively, just reboot the system more regularly - reboots will empty out /tmp.